# Effect of substituents on Ullmann reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

This question that I recently encountered asked what the most suitable substrate for the Ullmann reaction would be. The answer given is (b) but I think it has to be (d) as the nitro group acts as EWG and thus facilitates the reaction.

However I do not know the mechanism and thus am not sure if (d) is indeed the correct answer.

Any reason why the answer might be (b) and not (d)?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Ullmann's Reaction (similar to Wurtz) - aryl chloride with deactivating groups - stability of free radical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/46914/81509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the answer given in your textbook is wrong as they are trying to conduct ULLMANN reaction on a chloride a strong EWD needs to be present at the ortho/para positions for the reaction to be feasible.

There Are generally 2 Mechanisms Proposed for the reaction :

1. Free Radical Mechanism
2. Ionic Mechanism

> FREE RADICAL MECHANISM
>   The Copper Metal (used as catalyst) Generate a Aryl Radical By transferring a electron, and then 2 Aryl Radical combine to form the final product.
>   [image: FREE RADICAL MECHANISM]
>
> IONIC MECHANISM
>   Acording to this a Organometalic intermideate of Aryl copper halide is fromed. The copper is added to the Aryl halide by Oxidative addition. then a electron is transfered to the intermidiate to for a organocuppric radical which again perform the oxidative addition on another aryl halide which result in formation of a biaryl copper complex which in turn undergo reductive elimination and make the final product. 
>   [image]

You can easily see that we need a EWG to make the Reagent more reactive thus making the reaction feasible thus your answer must be either wrong or you might have checked it wrong. nevethless I also find [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40828-016-0036-2) affirming mine and your belief.

Source:

1. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40828-016-0036-2
2. www.name-reaction.com/ullmann-reaction

Comment: I may be wrong,but isn't a free radical destabilized by an EWG,considering that it is an electron deficient species? So why would EWGs facilitate the reaction?

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN no I don't  think so as the free readical is formed on a sp2 carbon

Comment: @AdvilSell See [this](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/08/02/3-factors-that-stabilize-free-radicals/) It clearly states that a free radical is an electron deficit species,and it's stability is similar to a carbocation

Comment: So even if -M effect is not operative then also -I effect surely is via the sigma bonds

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN yes i was mad when i wrote it , it has been a bad day till now please accept my apology i have edited the answer the EWG make the intermidate more reactive making the reaction faster as its a radical intermideate reaction the reaction is kinetically controlled

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Kabaj Its not so please read this https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40828-016-0036-2 and accept my apology

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Read the introduction part around the last para